# Trying to find an answer for my 92 Dakota not turning over

Tags: battery, starting, wiring, no-crank-no-start

I've changed the neutral safety switch and checked the wiring from the battery to the starter and the it still nothing but i can start it off the solenoid and it runs like a charm any suggestions

Comment: Have you checked the starter relay?

Answer (score 1):

The relay starter is responsible for the starter motor and/or solenoid.The only other part would be the ignition switch .So try to test the starter relay(you should hear a click at the electrical relay box when cranking ,if you dont then you need to replace it ,otherwise test the continuity between ignition switch poles.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by shorting the wires to the safety switch and see if it goes then - that circuit could be open somewhere else providing the same symptoms as a broken switch.